# How do I disable httpd service on startup (centos 5)

Tags: httpd, centos5

**Scenario**

Installed NGINX, so want to disable HTTPD from running after a server reboot. However when I have used the below commands, httpd starts again.

**Commands tried**

```
# service httpd stop
# chkconfig --level 2345 httpd off
# chkconfig --del httpd
# reboot
# service httpd status
```

After, I run a reboot but service shows as running when I checked service status. Any assistance appreciated

Comment: The `chkconfig --level 2345 httpd off` should have done it.  It should work without specifying the levels as well  `chkconfig httpd off`.  Are you sure it's init that's starting it up and not some other script that was put on there?

Comment: Is it actually running (via `ps aux`)? `service` checks for .pid file existance.

Comment: Turns out that it a conflict with the Plesk 11.5 installation. Plesk likes to maintain control through it's Portal, so essentially overwrites your changes unless you do things through that. A little frustrating to say the least.